# How do I calculate the invoice total after calling xrm.ConvertSalesOrderToInvoice() in the MS Dynamics CRM 2015 SDK?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm using the CRM 2015 Portal SDK (Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions 7.1.0 from NuGet), and trying to create an invoice based on an existing sales order. I can create the invoice, but the total is always zero until somebody views the invoice using the Dynamics CRM UI - and I can't find any way to force a recalculation via the SDK.

The SDK documentation (such as it is!) is a whopping great CHM file included in the SDK download, which is generated from XMLDoc comments - very little in the way of descriptions or examples. There's also the content at  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309408.aspx, which includes a couple of walkthroughs but doesn't go into very much detail.

Here's the code I'm running - this is inside an Action method in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project:

```
public ActionResult CreateInvoice(Guid id) {
  var xrm = new SpotlightXrmServiceContext("ConnectionStrings.Crm2015.Spotlight");
  var order = xrm.SalesOrderSet.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
  var columns = new ColumnSet(true);
  var invoiceEntity = xrm.ConvertSalesOrderToInvoice(order.Id, columns);
  return(View(invoiceEntity));
}
```

After running this code, the Invoice exists in the CRM database, and I can see it listed in the CRM UI by navigating to Sales > Invoices - but the invoice total is zero. If I click the invoice in the CRM UI to view it, something behind the scenes forces a recalculation, because when the invoice loads, the total is £154 (which is the total amount of the original sales order)

The web app in question is a post-payment redirect from our payment provider, so what I need to do from my web application is:

1. Locate the existing sales order
2. Create an invoice associated with that order
3. Mark the invoice as Paid
4. Mark the sales order as fulfilled

I appear to have fallen at the first hurdle. Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309346.aspx) help?

Comment: Have you already tried proceeding with step #3 and check if data is up-to-date afterwards ? I'd think it *should* take care of the data (never did this though, just an hypothesis)

Comment: @stuartd That looks incredibly helpful... thank you! Will check it out now.